# How can I read the numbers in a char array as integers?

Tags: c++

I want to pass dimension parameters of a matrix class as a char array, I can get the number of dimensions by counting the number of commas written in the parameters but I cant seem to read the numbers in a char as integers.

When I try to convert from char to int I get huge unrelated numbers. How can I read the numbers in a char array as integers?

```
template <class T>
matrix <T>::matrix (char * dimensions)
{
  int nod = 0;
  for(int i=0;dimensions[i];i++)
  {
    if (dimensions[i] == ',') nod++;
  }
  Number_of_dimensions = nod+1;
  //...
}
```

Comment: I don't see *any* reading code in there. That could be the problem.

Comment: You should probably better use some `std::istringstream` for parsing from character strings.

Comment: Did you try using a string-stream in the usual manner?

Comment: Jongware I tried reading code using type casting but it didnt work so I erased it.

Comment: Though it's not in the code above I think you're trying to cast a char to int instead of converting a string of chars to integer, try using `atoi`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following idea, illustrated with a rough pseudo-code snipper:

```
std::string s = "1234,4556";

//While you still have a string to parse
while (s.length()) {
    //Use a comma to delimit a token
    std::string delimiter = ",";

    //Find the position of the comma or the end of the string
    unsigned int comma_pos = s.find(delimiter);

    //Find the sub-string before the comma
    std::string token = s.substr(0, comma_pos); // token is "1234"

    //Find your int
    int i = std::stoi(token);

    //"Eat" the token, continue
    s.erase(0, comma_pos+1);
}
```

This is a particularly rough example, but the core idea is there: use std::string::substr() to find your sub-string with a comma delimiter, then convert the token to an int.

You also might want to consider looking for several delimiters, such as '\n'.

Comment: You may want to write `s.erase(0, comma_pos+1)`. And what about reading the last number? Prepare for situation where `comma_pos==std::string::npos`.

Comment: If it's std::string::npos, std::string::npos works in these functions as if it was the end of the line. Fixed the comma_pos+1

Comment: If `comma_pos` is `npos` then `s.erase(0, comma_pos+1)` won't work. You sould put an `if` there.

Answer (score 0):

`Split()` function splits string by delimiter. In our case delimiter is comma. The number of elements is dimension. Than we convert each element to number using `std::stringstream` (C++98, or std::stoi in C++11).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> Split(const std::string &s, char delim)
{
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim))
        elems.push_back(item);
    return elems;
}

std::vector<int> GetDim(char *dimensions)
{
    std::vector<std::string> dim_str = Split(dimensions, ',');
    std::vector<int> elems(dim_str.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim_str.size(); ++i) {
        std::stringstream ss(dim_str[i]);
        ss >> elems.at(i);
    }
    return elems;
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "1234,4556";
    std::vector<int> d = GetDim(&*s.begin());
    std::cout << "Dimensions: " << d.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Values: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << d[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I suggest you not to use pointer as arguments. Use `std::string` or `std::vector` instead. Do not forget `const` qualifier. So `GetDim()` can be:

```
std::vector<int> GetDim(const std::string& dimensions)
{
    std::vector<std::string> dim_str = Split(dimensions, ',');
    std::vector<int> elems(dim_str.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim_str.size(); ++i) {
        std::stringstream ss(dim_str[i]);
        ss >> elems.at(i);
    }
    return elems;
}
```